# iis7 application pool hanging

Tags: iis-7, pool

I have a .net 4.0 website that was running on physical Windows server 2003 boxes on IIS6 32bit just fine.  We have migrated to new virtual servers running Windows Server 2008 32 bit with IIS7.  The application pool is running in classic mode.

Since the move, I at random get a situation where the application hangs.  The request queue rockets and then I get 503 errors.  If the application pool is recycled, then the error goes away till the next time it occurs.

There are no entries in the event logs relating to it except that it notes when the application pool took to long to shut down during the recycle process.  I have reporting in my .net application that logs to a DB and sends me errors but it sends me nothing when this application is hanging.

What tools can I use to diagnose the problem and figure out what is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

In opinion, whatever the structure of application is, if you're pretty sure that there is no bug, changing sort of properties on the application pool might solve the problem.

First on the 'Advanced Settings...' menu of the application pool change the 'Enable 32-Bit Applications' to the relevant value. If the platform used for building application is x86 then the value should be 'True'.

Second if your application demands to access disk resources, also you should the relevant security context for running the application pool in the 'Identity' property. The identity should access all the directories that your application wants to change or list.

After doing all the things, in case the problem existed, you should let me know about the platform of your application. Is it .NET or ISAPI?

Cheers

Comment: I checked and the permissions seem to be correct.  It only needs access to the temp folder and a network share.  it has access to the network share and it is a member of IIS_Users which has access to the temp folder.

I am wondering if it is some com component that does not work on Server 2008 but does on Server2003.

I could not do the other setting change you suggested as the machine is 32bit and so does not provide me with those options

Comment: If your application is using ASP.NET, I recommend that comment all the Application_Start things and publish again. If it works means something at this event might be wrong. Also COM access needs the relevant Identity as I said. You can temporarily set the Identity property to LocalSystem and check the application starts. If it starts, you must have some security problems.

Comment: The application starts and operates correctly for a random amount of time and them some action that I cannot identify makes it hang.

Comment: You should put some trace conditions on the application source code and then review them to find out where is the interruption. By the way, there are many configurations that your application might be depended. So the sure way is the source way! Good luck.